# Automated Build script in VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, wix, build-automation

I have built an installer using WiX that consists of multiple .exe files that are 'Release' builds of other .Net projects (VS 2008). Each time I update one of the projects, I build that project and copy the Release build into the installer and then build and release the installer.

I find it a very tedious job to constantly check if the exe's that the installer has are the latest version or not. Is there a way that I can automate this build process so that as soon as I build the installer, it will generate the latest release builds of the associated projects and place the .exe file in the installer project.

I am new to VS and WiX, please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a Solution containing:

```
- all projects which build the EXEs
- the installer project which builds your installer
```

Once you are there, you should be able to right click on the Installer Project and set dependencies to all the projects which create your EXEs. You should be able to build your Solution with the right EXEs bundled in your Installer.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll go ahead and do that and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Arun's solution is great idea, and I recommend it.

We also have a lot of assemblies that we maintain, and rather than copying them around we use symbolic links to minimize the number of build-and-copy actions. You can research mklink (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) for details.

We use it like this, but we do this as part of our environment setup, and not part of our build script.

- mklink /project1/bin/project1.dll /project2/bin/project1.dll

This ensures for us that project2's reference to project1 is always up-to-date, whenever project1 is build, without needing to copy the file. In our case, project2 and project1 are not part of the same solution, and they have no direct references to one another (we do a lot of plugin-type reflection/assembly loading).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information Jamal. I guess we will have to follow something similar to yours as our assemblies are expanding widely and this solution is great. I'll definitely look into this.